# How to prove the monotonicity of the integral?

Tags: integration, monotone-functions

I want to know whether the following integral is decreasing in $\gamma$:

$$\int_1^{\infty} y^{1/\gamma} \int_0^{\infty}(1/\gamma+1)(w^{\gamma}+w^{\gamma}(y^{1/(\gamma\alpha)}-1)^{\gamma\alpha}+y)^{-1/\gamma-2} w^{\gamma} \left(\frac{w^{1/\alpha}}{w^{1/\alpha}+1}\right)^{-\alpha+3} dw\,dy,$$
with $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $\gamma>0$.

I computed this integral numerically with some specific values of $\alpha$ and observe that it is indeed decreasing in $\gamma$. For example, when $\alpha=0.5$:

[image]

But I still have no idea how to prove it theoretically. It is not easy to see whether the derivative is negative or not.

Thank you so much in advance!